# Phonon Test of speakers "Front Left" , "Front Right" is not working

Tags: kubuntu, kde, pulseaudio, phonon

I am using KDE 4.10, Kubuntu 13.04. My audio is working great. But when I configure Phonon and try to test the speakers, I don't get any sound.

When I start the configuration tool with:

```
kcmshell4 kcm_phonon
```

and press the "Front Left" or "Front Right" button, I get this error message:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM 0
```

Maybe the tool simply fails to load the wav test file? Where are they supposed to be located?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had, and fixed, the same problem with my installation. I guess you are using pulseaudio. The solution is to install the `libcanberra-pulse` package and the tests should work like a charm.

Comment: Whenever you happen to come round my street, I owe you a beer.

Comment: I am having the same problem, but libcanberra-pulse is already installed. At the moment I suspect that the recent switch to KDE5 broke a few things.

Comment: It seems to be a kcmshell4 vs 5 issue in my case?: https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=128063

Comment: Installing libcanberra-pulse solved it for me also on Arch Linux